# java project not getting analysed in sonar 3.3.5

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-analysis, sonar-runner

When I give mvn sonar:sonar for sample java project in sonar I get this error.The  sample project is from [link](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/maven)

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simple Java Maven Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) @ example-java-maven ---
[INFO] Sonar version: 3.5.1
[INFO] [12:29:59.781] Load batch settings
[INFO] [12:30:00.000] User cache: C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\.sonar\cache

[INFO] [12:30:00.156] Install plugins
INFO] [12:30:03.250] -------------  Executing Project Scan
[INFO] [12:30:04.500] Install JDBC driver
INFO] [12:30:04.515] Apply project exclusions
[WARN] [12:30:04.531] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
[INFO] [12:30:04.531] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
[INFO] [12:30:04.890] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [12:30:09.500] -------------  Inspecting Simple Java Maven Project
[INFO] [12:30:09.515] Load module settings
[INFO] [12:30:09.937] Excluded tests:
[INFO] [12:30:09.937]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.125s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 13 12:30:11 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/28M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (d
efault-cli) on project example-java-maven: Can not execute Sonar: You must insta
ll a plugin that supports the language 'java' -> [Help 1]
ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Should I manually put any plugin  to analyze java project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have removed the Java plugins from your Sonar home directory. You can upload the latest version at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Ecosystem, copy the plugins into SONAR_HOME/extensions/plugins and restart your Sonar server.

Comment: Thanks I have copied those jars into extensions/plugins now its working